# Problems with subdivision modifier on cylinders

Tags: subdivision-surface

I have a Problem, where on details at a Cylinder plus subdivision surface, edges of those details get a bit deformed as seen here [image: here] and here [image: here]

I only have found  a solution by adding crease to the vertical edges along the loops like here [image: here] Is there any other way of fixing this? because with this solution my subdivision modifier gets obsolete.

Comment: every quad is based upon 2 triangles, subdevison can act weird if mesh layout isnt ideal, you'll have to dive in the topic of topology http://topologyguides.com/post/163679954765/loop-reduction

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Try adding support loops like this instead. Dont use creases. you have to add support loops in the right way to make the creasing look good. Merge the verts shown by red dots.